# Page 'slides' after button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

My site uses a full page main div which fades when the user scrolls down revealing content underneath. I have an animated scroll-down button so that users will know that there's more content if they scroll down (they need to scroll roughly 150px before it fades)

I would like the button to 'push/slide' the page down that distance when clicked, similar to if the user scrolled down instead. Ideally there would be an ease to that push/slide so that it isn't just a hard jolt to the content.

html

```
<header class="hide-header">
  <div id="scl-btn-wrap" class="bounce">
    <a id="scl-btn" class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-lg" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</header>
```

I have a scoll-up button when the user gets to the bottom which works, but can't figure out how to essentially do the opposite for a set difference

html

head

```
<script> 
function scrolltop(){ $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0}, 800,"swing"); } 
window.onload = function() { window.scrollTo(0, 0);}
</script>
```

footer.php

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="scrolltop();"></a>
```

Comment: please create an working model. Only code is not helpful for such problem

Comment: You are going in the right direction with jQuery's animate function to scroll the document. Try attaching that behavior to the button click, instead of doing an onload. Something like `$('#scl-btn').on('click', function(){ ... })`.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is a bit different. I have that code applied to a button which slides the page back to the top. I want a button that slides the page down a certain amount (like 500px) when clicked. Also with easing (so it's not abrubt stop at 500px)